# Public pianos in the U.S

Tags: usa, online-resources, tips-and-tricks, where-on-earth, music

I've been to the Rock'n Roll Hall of Fame in Cleveland last year and had some [fun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1KocECdNag) on a [piano in their lobby with a sign saying "Play me, I'm yours"](http://streetpianos.com/cleveland2013/pianos/rock-and-roll-hall-of-fame-and-museum/). I did some research and found a pretty cool project called [Street Pianos](http://www.streetpianos.com). They basically put pianos in public places all around a city for a limited time and invite everyone to play them. The one at the Rock'n Roll Hall of Fame was kept after the event in Cleveland finished.

There are some new cities scheduled for 2016, but unfortunately nothing near my upcoming trip (L.A., New Mexico and Texas). What would be my best options to find a piano somewhere, that I can play for a couple of minutes (free or paid)? The idea is to record a short clip in an interesting setting on a nice piano. I'm no professional musician, but I think I'm decent enough not to annoy people or destroy an expensive instrument. It's not the number one priority on my trip, but something I'd love to do, if there's a chance. Do you have any ideas - for my specific trip, but also in general?

Comment: if you happen to travel to France some day, [many big train stations](http://www.sncf.com/fr/presse/carte/pianos-gares) have some, which are popular

Comment: Wow, that's nice! Thanks for the info, I'll check them out soon.

Comment: If you make it up to Portland, there's a program every summer to place pianos around the city: http://www.pianopushplay.com/pianos/

Comment: Thanks, Julian! Sounds like another good reason to visit Portland!

Comment: Note that you may want to double-check previous Street Pianos locations, as in some instances, the pianos are still there. For instance, there are still 3 Street Pianos in St Pancras station in London (and more in a few other locations in London), even though they were originally planned just for 2012. This is stated on the Street Pianos page for that city. They don't say anything about remaining pianos in Austin or LA though :-(

Comment: Interestingly enough, even though St Pancras has already three (but the one outside Eurostar arrivals has at least a key that is seriously out of tune), [Elton John donated a new one](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3432075/Elton-John-performs-St-Pancras-station.html)

Comment: Not the US, but I just discovered one in London. Heathrow airport, Terminal 3 on the way to gates 24 & 26-42. Perfect for travelers, just don't miss your flight.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Public Pianos Worldwide

Placing pianos in public spaces has become increasingly popular over the past years, to the point that it's hard to pinpoint who did it first and why. Arguably, the most well-known project is [Street Pianos](http://www.streetpianos.com/), however this is definitely not the only project. Indeed, [private local organisations](http://www.singforhope.org/what-we-do/), [city councils](http://ville.montreal.qc.ca/portal/page?_pageid=5977,128115575&_dad=portal&_schema=PORTAL), [public park authorities](http://pianosintheparks.com/find-a-park-piano/), [railway companies](http://www.sncf.com/fr/presse/carte/pianos-gares), and many others have joined in this practice across the world.

The projects are so extensive and localised at the same time, both permanent and temporary, that your question might actually be too broad for Travel SE. The web is scattered with pages on the topic, and maps of pianos. However there is no guarantee that the installations might still be there in the future. It is worthy to note that most outdoor pianos are taken out during the summer and stored away during the rest of the year. Nevertheless, maps are indeed available, therefore I'll summarise my findings nonetheless.

#### Street Pianos - Worldwide

[Street Pianos](http://www.streetpianos.com/) has been running the *Play Me I'm Yours* project since 2008, adding and relocating pianos in various cities across the world. Quoting from their website:

> Who plays them and how long they remain on the streets is up to each community.

Street Pianos provide a [global map of currently available pianos, which can be found here.](http://www.streetpianos.com/map/) To date, the project covers 15 cities in the USA.

#### Piano! Push Play! - Portland, Oregon

[Piano! Push Play!](http://www.pianopushplay.com/what-we-do/) is another project, which places pianos in public spaces during the summer, and puts those pianos away in schools and community centres where people can play them throughout the year. The project was born in Portland, Orgeon, and to date this seems to be the only they cover.

The best way to locate the pianos is to [use the dedicated app](http://www.pianopushplay.com/55837358e4b0fdbf809290a4/), which shows a map of available instruments. The pianos will also contact you, via the app, when you find yourself close enough to one of them. Alternatively, [there is a project webpage detailing all the pianos](http://www.pianopushplay.com/pianos/) which you can browse for detailed information.

#### The Sing for Hope Pianos - New York City

Sing For Hope is a charity who runs [a public pianos project in New York City for two weeks during the summer](http://www.singforhope.org/what-we-do/). After which the pianos are donated to local community-based organisation. In 2015, 88 pianos were made available in 5 boroughs across the city. It is likely that the project will run again in 2016, and a map will be rendered available online in due course.

#### Pianos In Public Spaces - San Diego

[The San Diego Symphony rung a public piano project in San Diego.](http://www.sandiegosymphony.org/playme/) In 2016, from FRIDAY, January 8 – SATURDAY, FEBRUARY 8, 8 public pianos, [whose location can be found on the map here](http://www.sandiegosymphony.org/static/media/uploads/Piano%20Festival/pips-map.png), were made available.

#### And Many More

Finally, if none of the projects above cover your needs, try querying your favourite search engine for `public pianos YYY`, where `YYY` is the city you will be travelling to, to see if local `YYY` organisations have a public piano project running.

Answer (score 3):

I have two answers, since you've asked for both **free** pianos to play and pianos that you that you can **pay** to play.

For free pianos, I've found that you can get the most up-to-date information by searching social media (Twitter or Instagram) which often includes location tags about where the pianos are, so you can see if they are still up-to-date (try a hashtag like #publicpiano when searching). There are many organizations that promote parks or music by temporarily installing public pianos and these can often be found with social media as they often have that hashtag. There are a few websites that catalog the free pianos including [Piano Players Club](https://www.pianoplayersclub.com/), [Airport Piano wiki](https://airport-pianos.fandom.com/wiki/Airport_pianos_Wiki), and [Pianos for Travelers](https://pianos.travel/) (this last one seemingly the most complete).

If you can pay for a piano, then there is actually a website [PianoMe](https://piano.me/) which allows you to book pianos around the world. In addition, you can search for AirBNB and VRBO listings that include pianos using [Pianos for Travelers](https://pianos.travel) so that you could actually rent a house/apartment that has a piano.